# Span-Columns not working in IE9

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer-9, bourbon, neat

I am using Bourbon Neat and Bitters on a custom Wordpress Theme project.
Having coded the layout I am stuck getting it to look right in IE

[Temporary URL of the site.](http://test.xperiorfarmhealth.co.uk/version-2/)

[A working example using a static site with the same markup.](http://test.xperiorfarmhealth.co.uk/test.grids/)

An overview of the SCSS:

```
@import "bourbon/bourbon";
@import "bitters/bitters";
@import "neat/neat";

@import "mixins"; 


html {
    background: #064831 url('img/Page-BG-Grad-1800.jpg') repeat-y top center;
    background-size: 120%;
    padding: {
            left: 3%;
            right: 3%;
        }
    margin: 0;
        @include media ($mobile) { 
            background-image: none;
            background: #fff;
            padding: {
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
            }
        }
}

body {
    @include outer-container;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #fff;

}

.wrapper {
    @include outer-container;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;

    @include media ($tablet) {
        width: 95%;
        max-width: 95%;
    }
    @include media ($desktop) {
        width: 87%;
        max-width: 87%;
    }

}



    .left-column {
        @include span-columns(6);
    }
    .right-column {
        @include span-columns(6);
        @include omega;
    }
```

And the markup outputted from Wordpress:

```
<body class="home page page-id-2 page-template page-template-template-home-page-php logged-in" >

    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="highlight">
            <p><strong>LATEST NEWS:</strong></p>
        </div>

        <section class="left-column">
            <p>Column 1</p>
        </section>

        <section class="right-column">
            <p>Column 2</p>
        </section>

    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: All columns are 100% in IE, even though Firebug (in browserstack) say's they're 48.93%

Comment: It seems this is not related to Bourbon or Neat, it's fixed by removing:

'<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> '

in the header of the site. This code was imported from HTML5Boilerplate but seems to break the site when in a wordpress theme.